# tableview:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath how to stop delete button from showing on some cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I would like to know if there is anyway to stop the "clear" button from appearing on a specific uitableviewcell and let it appear on another?

I have set up a custome uitableview cell that has a button in it, I am using the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

method.. I would like to know if you can stop the button that apprears on one of several uitableviewcells when the user swipes to delete?

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Clear";
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) 
    {
        //cell fade - notifies the user that they are edited their cell
        NSArray *rowArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        if (indexPath.row == 0) 
        {

            manufactureSearchObjectString = @"empty";
            [self.tableView reloadData]; //reloads the tabel with new value
            manufactureResultIndexPath = nil; //removes tick from subview

        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
        {

        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2) 
        {

        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 3)
        {
            keyTypeSearchObjectString = @"empty";
            [self.tableView reloadData]; //reloads the tabel with new value
            keyTypeResultIndexPath = nil; //removes tick from subview

        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) 
    {
        if (indexPath == 0) 
        {
            //can I stop the "clear" button from showing in here?
        }
    }
}
```

To be a bit more specific I am wanting to stop this from happening
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USe below method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
            if (indexPath.section == 1) 
            {
              if (indexPath.row == 0) 
              {
                 return NO;// you can  stop the "clear" button from showing in here?
              }
              else
                return YES;
            }
          else
            return YES;


    }
```